# Getting error in listeners after extending my selenium TestNG framework to Cucumber

Tags: selenium, cucumber, testng, listener, extentreports

Q1) I have an existing framework in Selenium-TestNG along with Listeners class. I close the browser using @AfterTest annotation of TestNG:

```
 @AfterTest
    public void teardown()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }
```

Here onTestSuccess method of Listeners class works perfectly fine when I run as plain old Selenium TestNG without cucumber feature file:

```
public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) 
    {
        test.log(Status.PASS, "Test case Passed");
                
        try 
        {
        String path = takeScreenshot(driver, "Pass/" + result.getInstanceName() + "/" + result.getMethod().getMethodName());        
        test.addScreenCaptureFromPath(path, result.getMethod().getMethodName());
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            log.fatal("Exception in onTestSuccess Method of Listeners class");
            log.fatal(e.getMessage() +" : " + e.getStackTrace());
            System.out.println("Exception " + e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Exception " + e.getStackTrace());
        }
    }
```

When Test passes, onTestSuccess() method of Listeners class is called first and then teardown() method is called. So every thing goes smooth.

Now I use this feature file in cucumber:

```
Feature: Logout feature

Background: 
    Given User is on Salesforce login page
  
  @SmokeTest @Low @PositiveTest @Logout
  Scenario: Logout of application
    Given "RMUser" has logged into Salesforce application
    When User clicks on logout button
    Then Users is logged-out from the application
```

And use @After hook to close the browser:

```
@After
    public void teardown() {        
        driver.quit();
    }
```

Now when I run this feature file as TestNG then teardown method in Hooks file is called first and then onTestSuccess() method of Listeners class is called due to which I get error "**Exception Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?**" at the line where I try to use driver variable:

```
String path = takeScreenshot(driver, "Pass/" + result.getInstanceName() + "/" + result.getMethod().getMethodName());
```

This can be resolved if onTestSuccess() method of Listeners class is called first before @After hook gets called.

**Seeking some workaround or idea to resolve this issue in Cucumber**.

Q2) While running as plain Selenimm-TestNG, Extent Reports gives the correct TestName in the report but when running as TestNG Cuccumber framework, Extent reports just shows all the test names as "runScenario".

[image: ExtentReport when run in cucumber framework]

**How to make ExtentReport give proper feature file scenario names instead of just "runScenario"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the TestNG Listeners class exception by removing driver.quit(); from Hooks class file and putting it inside onTestStart and onTestFailure methods of the Listeners class:

```
public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) 
    {
        test.log(Status.PASS, "Test case Passed");
        
        
        try 
        {
        String path = takeScreenshot(driver, "Pass/" + result.getInstanceName() + "/" + result.getMethod().getMethodName());        
        test.addScreenCaptureFromPath(path, result.getMethod().getMethodName());
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            log.fatal("Exception in onTestSuccess Method of Listeners class");
            log.fatal(e.getMessage() +" : " + e.getStackTrace());
            System.out.println("Exception " + e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Exception " + e.getStackTrace());
        }
        driver.quit();
    }

    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        test.log(Status.FAIL, "Test case Failed");
        test.fail(result.getThrowable());   
        
        try 
        {       
        String path = takeScreenshot(driver, "Fail/" + result.getInstanceName() + "/" + result.getMethod().getMethodName());        
        test.addScreenCaptureFromPath(path, result.getMethod().getMethodName());        
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            log.fatal("Exception in onTestFailure Method of Listeners class");
            log.fatal(e.getMessage() +" : " + e.getStackTrace());
            System.out.println("Exception " + e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Exception " + e.getStackTrace());
        }
        driver.quit();
    }
```

Since the testcase will either pass or fail hence control will always come either  in onTestSuccess or onTestFailure methods and this will quit the driver after Testcase is completed execution.